# Simple java program won't read file

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am very new to programming and am having a lot of trouble trying to read data from a text file.

1. My first problem arose trying to create a new Scanner object for my file. I got a "file not found" error unless I added .getAbsolutePath() after the file object.
2. Now, I can't seem to read any data from the file. When I try to print each line in the file I get no output.

I assume I'm just missing something very obvious. Can anyone help me out?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputFile = new File("menu.txt");
    System.out.println("Reading from file" + inputFile);
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(inputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    String answer;

    while (inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
        answer = inputScanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(answer);

    }
}
```

EDIT: I originally was passing the file object into my creation of the scanner object, but was still getting the error.

Comment: `File.getAbsolutePath` returns a `String`. And a `Scanner(String)` does **not** read from a `File` (it reads only that `String`).

Comment: It's menu.txt in my project directory. I even listed out all of the files in my project directory and the path printed out fine. I also tried using the full path instead of just menu.txt

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: has found a more pressing issue

Comment: Do this: `System.out.println(new File("menu.txt").getAbsolutePath());`. I can virtually guarantee the full path isn't what you think it is.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the full path is exactly what I expected it to be. I even tried passing that output (the full path) as my argument for the file creation, and I still get the FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to use `Scanner` to read from the file, whereas `Scanner` is used to read tokens (e.g. lines) from a given string.  Instead, you should use a `Reader` to read your file:

```
File inputFile = new File("menu.txt");
System.out.println("Reading from file" + inputFile);
BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
String answer;

while ((answer = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

**UPDATE:** You *can* use a scanner if you really want to - but then you need to pass `Path` object to the constructor:

```
File inputFile = new File("menu.txt");
System.out.println("Reading from file" + inputFile);
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
String answer;

while (inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
    answer = inputScanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(answer);

}
```

(Note that I didn't test this code.)

Comment: This confuses me since a Scanner can read from a File just fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Scanner can read from a file - correct - but then the file should be supplied as a path, not a string.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: @AleksG There is a suitable `Scanner` constructor which takes a `File` argument. There should be no need to convert it to a `Path` first.

Comment: Hi Aleks, thanks for the response. The updated answer is actually what I originally had, and gives me the error. I tried your first solution and I'm still getting the FileNotFoundException, so I'm starting to think that the problem is something outside of the actual code.

Comment: Well, if you get `FileNotFoundExcepiton`, that means that either the file is not there, really, or your program is looking for it in the wrong place.  Put `System.err.println(inputFile.getAbsolutePath())` in there and make sure it prints the correct thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Test {
//The file should be in contained within the root of your project.
//  When you execute a project in eclipse, the working directory is the most top level of your project.
//  Right click your project, click New>File, and make a txt file called "TheGame.txt".
private static final String FILENAME = "menu.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try (BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME))) {
         System.out.println("Reading from file" + inputFile);

        String answer;

        while ((answer = inputFile.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(answer);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```